# Adjusting Compression Factor For Sox Merge of mono Wav and Ogg files

Tags: bash, wav, sox, ogg

I am using Sox to take a mono ogg file and merge it with a mono wav file to create a stereo ogg file. The ogg file becomes the left channel, and the wav file becomes the the right channel.

When I do this, Sox applies a steep lowpass filter at around 18khz to the final ogg file, leading me to believe it is applying a second round of compression that is of lower quality than the original compression.

I am trying to figure out how I can merge the two pieces of audio together, while explicitly using some compression factor (10 for highest quality).

I have tried to append -C 10 to different parts of the sox command with failed results.

When I take the original ogg file and re-compress with a compression factor of 10, there is no observable low pass filter at 18khz.

Here is my current sox command

```
sox -M file.ogg file.wav merged.ogg
```

What I'm trying to achieve - merge the files but state a compression factor so there's no lowpass filtering/observable loss in quality

```
sox -M file.ogg file.wav -C 10 merged.ogg
```

Compressing the ogg without seeing a lowpass filter/loss in quality

```
sox file.ogg -C 10 output.ogg
```

Anyone know how the merge command functions with two different input types and how to modify the compression factor for it?

Comment: The format is in the manual, it's `sox [global-options] [format-options] infile1
    [[format-options] infile2] ... [format-options] outfile
    [effect [effect-options]] ...`. Try `sox file.ogg -C 10 output.ogg`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax - my issues lie with what I'm piping into ffmpeg which is why I could not see this command working as intended:

sox -M left.ogg right.wav -C10 output.ogg